# What's the difference between Html body and head tags?

Tags: css, html, head, document-body

I have a code snippet which goes as follows:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<p>Hello I am Dikshit</p>
<ul><li class="">Hello</li>
<li> India</li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</head>
<body>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
Hello Lorem popum
<p> Demo text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How does this even work? What is the difference between head and body tags?
[Please find here the output attachment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlMEN.jpg)

Comment: this is for sure invalid HTML but it does work because your browser is clever enough ... but this should not work

Comment: Some _tags_ are optional in HTML, so when the parser encounters the first tag not allowed inside the head element, it automatically closes the head element before that. Same thing vice versa with body - that gets _opened_ implicitly due to that. If you validate your code, your will see error messages resulting from that, such as "Stray end tag head" and "Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open." - https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: @TemaniAfif I obviously know that it is invalid html. But my question was why did it even work at the first place?

Comment: because your browser is clever :) ... people who implemented browser will not give you a red screen for invalid html even if there is a small missing tag, they will try to get around with all this mess in order to produce something that will work ... BUT you should not rely on this, this is a behavior that you cannot control and you need to follow the specification.

Answer (score 1):

The `head` tag is [supposed to be used for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML) information for including resources/information for the browser/search engines, so stuff like CSS `link`s and `script`s and `meta` tags.

If you add a `div` or any other visible HTML element, most browsers will still show it, but it's [not technically valid](https://validator.w3.org/check) and is advised against -- just put visible content in the `body`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it works is that the browser knows what you wanted to do. But you might have troubles when you host it in an external server.
Tags help you structure your page. If a robot crawls your web, it knows to look for tags that define your webpage in the head, and for the content that is defined in the body.